# Executar Artisan Migrate em bancos dinâmicos

Tags: php, laravel, migrations

Salve, salve pessoal!

Estou com um problema em um projeto com múltiplos banco de dados, cada banco de dados corresponde a um usuário que é criado quando o usuário confirma seu cadastro.

Criei um command especifico para isso. e esta funcionando perfeitamente, o usuário confirma seu cadastro através de do seu e-mail e bingo! o banco de dado é ciado com seu numero de contrato no sufixo.

A dificuldade que estou enfrentando é de rodar o migrate nesse momento.É sabido que para trabalhar com multi database é necessário ter um schema padrão configurado no .env.

então estou fazendo o seguinte, onde db:create é um comando criado.

```
  public function workspaceConfig($id)
    {
        $dataBaseName = 'apl_'.$id;
        Artisan::call("db:create ". $dataBaseName);
        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $dataBaseName);
        DB::reconnect();
        Artisan::call('migrate:refresh', [
            '--force' => true,
        ]);
        Config::set('database.default','mysql'); 
        DB::reconnect();
    }
```

Retorna o seguinte:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'apl_15.migrations' doesn't exist (SQL: select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc)",
```

meu .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=apl_padrao
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=minhasenha
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Por que ao invés de usar o migrate, você não cria uma DB::query com uma query criando a tabela?

Comment: Glenys Mitchell, o projeto já esta pronto são mais de 100 tabelas já codificadas, a criação de tabelas através de DB::query esta fora do escopo do projeto.

Comment: Qual das linhas está dando erro e o erro atual é que não existe a tabela...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boas, consegui resolver.
Quando o método executa o Artisan::call('migrate') é necessário chamar um conexão diferente da conexão padrão, então ficou assim:

```
public function workspaceConfig($id)
    {
        $dataBaseName = 'aa_'.$id;
        \Artisan::call("db:create ". $dataBaseName);
        \Config::set('database.connections.client.database', $dataBaseName);
        DB::reconnect('client');
            Artisan::call('migrate', array(
                '--database' => 'client', 
                '--force'=> true
            ));
        DB::purge('tenant');
        DB::reconnect('mysql');
    }
```

e no config/database.php assim:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => '',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

e mantenho o .env em:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=apl_padrao
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=minhasenha
```

dessa forma funcionou!